# REST Java web service using protobuf

Tags: java, rest, protocol-buffers

I want to implement a REST web service using Java & protobuf.

Can anyone point me to where to start or how to implement it? Any good tutorial??

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below two article shows you exactly this

1. [Using JAX-RS with Protocol Buffers for high-performance REST APIs](http://www.javarants.com/2008/12/27/using-jax-rs-with-protocol-buffers-for-high-performance-rest-apis/)
2. [RESTful Representation with Google Protocol Buffers and Jersey](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2010/03/restful-representation-with-google.html)

Comment: Please correct the first link to: https://javarants.com/using-jax-rs-with-protocol-buffers-for-high-performance-rest-apis-563ce40d15d9

Answer (score 3):

You can see inside the post how we can create a JX-RS web service which is producing Google protocol Buffer in response. Source code is available [at my blog](http://cs-notes-amir.blogspot.com/2012/11/google-protocol-buffers-jx-rs-maven.html)

what I am doing is converting the protocol buffer object into byte array from server side and sending is array via service:
Service code is below , populating object and putting it in response.

```
UserDTO.User user = UserDTO.User.newBuilder(). //protocol buffer object
          setSessionId(id).
          setName("l070020").
          build();
return Response.ok(user.toByteArray(),MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).status(200).build();
```

Protocol buffer object has ability to parse and populate populate the protocol buffer object via stream.
So i am using by stream for data communication.
On client side I am making connection to web service

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/maven.work/service/mainServices/get_user");
request.addHeader("accept","application/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Protocol buffer has  built in method to parse stream, below I am parsing stream from the response

```
User user = User.parseFrom(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Similarly you can send the protocol buffer object in the form of byte array to server and server can get it from HTTP Servlet Request stream and parse it same like the client is doing.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: In addition to what j0k noted above, please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: On the above link i have written the complete solution and code,But if u guys think that post is not guaranteed to be alive I will put code guide lines here and putting the link for reference.Thanks for guiding me. i am new at stackoverflow.

Comment: I have added the required disclosure that the blog you are linking to is your own.

Comment: ok, my blog is technical blog and i am trying to create solution of different programming issue inside my blog and put its post as reference on other technical blogs

Answer (score 1):

To begin simple, you can write a plain servlet and return the seralization of your data with protobuf. For REST i prefer [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/docs.html). Maybe this helps further: [Google protocol buffers and servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162117/google-protocol-buffers-and-servlets)